# How to import a excel file as its own name in matlab

Tags: excel, matlab, plot, import, xlsread

I am trying to import 298 excel files into matlab. I was able to import them into an array within another cell array. (Not sure if this is the most effective method) I would like to save them as their filenames as they appear in excel and then plot the x and y coordinates. I was hoping to use comet to plot the coordinates. They all have a different name so nothing will get overridden. Is there a function to do this? Any other information would be appreciated.

Comment: *I would like to save them as their filenames as they appear in excel and then plot the x and y coordinates* as in the file `something.xlsx` is saved into variable named `something`?

Comment: Please can you show an example of the data, the code you have already written, what result you currently get, and what it is that you still need to achieve? It's not clear from your question where your actual problem is.